# Find directories by name where parent directory contains a certain filename

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to get a list of directories with the name vendor where the parent directory also contains a file with the name composer.json.

**Some context:**

For a simple backup script I want to exclude generated files/folders such as `node_modules` (generated by NPM) and `vendor` (generated by Composer).

I can simply exclude all folders with the name `node_modules` because it is almost certain that it was generated by NPM. Though, the `vendor` folder, created by Composer, is a very common name, so I want to check if there is a `composer.json` file in the parent directory. If there is then I can assume that the `vendor` folder was generated by Composer.

Is there an efficient way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work:

```
find -type d -name vendor -execdir test -e composer.json \; -print
```

Comment: Yep, that works! 
Is there a way to print the full path?

Comment: Using `find "$(pwd)"` in place of `find` will do that.

Comment: is there a way to modify the command to remove all these `vendor` folders?

Comment: @bilogic To delete all of the folders it currently prints, just change `-print` to `-delete`.